# Can't find Gaius Maro's body after killing him in Solitude

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

For the quest "Breaching Security", you're to kill Gaius Maro (preferably in a town) and then place a letter on his body.

I followed him to Solitude and transformed into a werewolf to kill him, to avoid the bounty. I then ran outside to transform back, planning to return inside Solitude then.

When I got back in however, the marker for his body seems to be underground, near where I killed him. It's not a door marker. Is this a glitch where his body has disappeared, or has his body been moved somewhere (like the Hall of the Dead)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that his body is indeed underground. Werewolf attacks often fling corpses behind objects, or it could've been a glitch during area transition. Are you playing on the PC? If yes, then you can move his body to yourself by typing `prid 44051` followed by `moveto player` in the console. Otherwise your best bet would be to reload a save prior to killing him or leaving the area, if you have one. On the PC, a backup copy of your previous quicksave is kept, which you can restore by removing the second .bak extension. Perhaps a similar technique could be used on a console.